# Power BI embed code throws 403 forbidden error from server. How to fix this?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

The embedded power BI dashboard is displaying in my sub-domain 'a.mydomain.com' and in my localhost.
But it's not displaying in my another sub-domain 'b.mydomain.com'.

FYI I'm embedding the powerBI via javascript and JWT encoded token.

In 'b.mydomain.com', the js code when trying to access report via ajax returning 403 forbidden error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9fSc.png)

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking and mis-tagging it "embedded" does not help.  On the face of it however it sounds like a network infrastructure issue rather than a coding issue so perhaps inappropriate for SO?

Comment: I've used embedded power bi reports(via js) in my web application. the dashboard is displaying in my local machine and in my "a.mydomain.com". But it's not displaying the dashboard in "b.mydomain.com". while debugging from browsers console, it says 403 error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all parameters are set correctly in the JWT token, sometimes different domains mean different timezone which might affect the ValidFrom\ ValidTo properties.. The error you are receiving is of TokenValidationFailure, which means it not even reaching the data access step before it fails.. which might suggest something to do with the content of the token itself...

Validate your parameters, in regards to times, timezones, audiences etc.